# sitemap for django-angular website

Tags: django, angular, sitemap

I have a website with django angular 5. I want to create sitemap for this website. I know how to create sitemap in django alone. but I do not know how to create sitemap when my front-end is angular 5.

Comment: Why would angular 5 prevent you from using `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/sitemaps/`?

Comment: When we want to create sitemap in django, we must set url. should I define route of angular in django sitemap?

Comment: If you want the sitemap to show the root you would define it.  Perhaps the issue is you're only calling the angular page once and then only refresh widgets within it.  If so, I don't know how to help